# What is the distributional derivative of this characteristic function on the square?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega = [0,1] \times [0,1] \subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as
$$ f(s,t) = \chi_S $$
with $ S = [0,\tfrac{1}{2}] \times (\tfrac{1}{2},1] \cup (\tfrac{1}{2},1] \times [\tfrac{1}{2},1] $

I would like to compute $\partial_1 f \in \mathcal{M}(\Omega)$, i.e. the distrbutional partial derivative w.r.t. the first variable, which must be (as far as I know) a measure on the square $\Omega$.

I have an idea of what I should get, although I am not sure: a measure $\nu$ concentrated on the subset $ \{ s=\tfrac{1}{2} \} $ such that, named $T_1 = \{\tfrac{1}{2}\} \times [0,\tfrac{1}{2})$ and $ T_2 = \{\tfrac{1}{2}\} \times (\tfrac{1}{2},1]$

$$ \nu = \mathcal{H}_{T_1} - \mathcal{H}_{T_2} $$

where $\mathcal{H}_T$ stands for the Hausdorff measure on the set $T$.

My **first question** is: is this correct? Does something special happen in the point $(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2})$ (for example some Dirac delta pops up)?

My **second question** is much more vague: if not, is anyone aware of some natural way to make a Dirac delta pop up?

Comment: Do you know the definition of distributional derivative? If yes, could you tell us where is your difficulty to help us help you?

Comment: @LL3.14 The distributional derivative $T'$ of a distribution $T$ acts on test functions $\varphi$ as $T'(\varphi)=T(\varphi')$. This means that I am looking for a measure $\nu$ such that $ \int \partial_1\varphi f dsdt = \int \varphi d\nu$, I think.

Comment: @LL3.14 I saw I forgot a minus sign. However, that seems right to me. I have a sense that I cannot obtain a Dirac delta as I could have in the one-dimensional case (take e.g. the havyside step function), but I actually have no idea how to see it...

Comment: @rod. You will obtain a couple of Dirac deltas, times something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for these kind of situations, it is normally sufficient to come back to the definitions, that is for a distribution $f$, its gradient $\nabla f$ is defined as the distribution acting on test functions (smooth and compactly supported) $\varphi$ through the formula
$$
\langle \nabla f,\varphi\rangle = -\langle f,\nabla\varphi\rangle.
$$
In the particular case of $f = \chi_S$, since $\chi_S$ is a locally integrable function, its action as a distribution is given by an integral, that is
$$
\langle \nabla f,\varphi\rangle = -\iint_\Omega f\,\nabla\varphi
\\
= -\int_0^{1/2}\!\!\!\!\int_{1/2}^1 \nabla\varphi -\int_{1/2}^1\!\!\int_{1/2}^1 \nabla\varphi
\\
= -\int_0^{1}\!\!\!\!\int_{1/2}^1 \nabla\varphi(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x.
$$
Since $\varphi$ is compactly supported on $[0,1]^2$, it is in particular $0$ when $x$ or $y$ is close to $0$ or $1$, so integrating the derivatives gives only values near $1/2$, and more precisely,
$$
\langle \nabla f,\varphi\rangle = \left(0, \int_0^1 \varphi(x,1/2)\,\mathrm d x\right).
$$
This can be interpreted as some kind of "Dirac line" on the line $y=1/2$, pointing towards $y=1$ (where it goes up). Notice that $\chi_S = \chi_A$ a.e. where $A = [0,1]\times[1/2,1]$, so they define the same distribution. A more formal way to write this would be to define the distribution $\delta_{[0,1]\times\{1/2\}}$ as the distribution acting on tests functions through the formula $\langle \delta_{[0,1]\times\{1/2\}},\varphi\rangle = \int_0^1 \varphi(x,1/2)\,\mathrm d x$, then
$$
\langle \nabla f,\varphi\rangle = \left(0, \delta_{[0,1]\times\{1/2\}}\right).
$$
This can also be written
$$
\langle \nabla f,\varphi\rangle = \left(0, 1\otimes\delta_{\{1/2\}}\right).
$$